# How to remove back history in framework7?

Tags: angularjs, html-framework-7

I am the beginner for framework7.I don't know how to remove back() button navigation history in framework7 js. I am developing multiple pages, each page contains different contents so I used and create it.For example like this login.html,home.html,logout.html. 
Now I am going to home.html(page) using `mainView.route.loadPage('home.html')` from login.html(page) 
then I go to logout.html(page) using `mainView.route.loadPage('logout.html')` when I clicked logout button it's going to login page.see what's my problem is after logout when I clicked back browser button it going to again logout->home recursively

Answer (score 0):

You can remove login page from history

```
for (var i = 0; i < mainView.history.length; i++) {
  if (mainView.history[i] === 'login.html') mainView.history.splice(i,1);
}

//So when you are on home page, login page sit on left:
$$('.view-main .page-on-left, .view-main .navbar-on-left').remove();
```